GURPS Trinket Magic History
I was looking at some GURPs PDFs, and one (probably Ritual Magic) mentioned a form of magic where the practitioner used a ritual to cast a spell on an object, and then later activated that object with a command word or by breaking it.
It's a neat idea, since the mechanical outcome seems very similar to Vancian magic at first blush, but it has the wrinkle that you can refresh your low level "spell slots" with a quick ritual during virtually any break in the action, while some high level rituals might need extended downtime with expensive components and helpful allied casters to recover. So a "long rest" might not be long enough to get back your best tools!
The idea also felt very familiar; I'm sure I read a book (urban fantasy maybe?) where this kind of magic was common.
So inspired in part by this question on Vancian Magic - What's the history of GURPs trinket based ritual magic?
Did this idea start in fiction, or GURPs or some other TTRPG? What is the origin of this mechanic?

FWIW, this "one shot magic item" concept is at the core of the Cypher System (Numenorea and The Strange core system), though they surely didn't originate it.

Well, it has a precedent in Advanced Wizard (published 1980), the second magic system book for The Fantasy Trip (TFT), the RPG designed by Steve Jackson before GURPS.
There, as in GURPS and the 2018 republication of The Fantasy Trip, there is a magic system (similar to standard GURPS magic, but different in various details) which has both systems for creating (and inventing/developing) permanent magic item enchantments, and also a limited amount of a similar sort of item that GURPS calls trinkets.
In TFT, there are a few specific spells and enchantments that are disposable or single-use, in particular, gems that you break (generally by throwing at the floor) to create a one-time spell effect:

Explosive gems
Dazzle gems
Summoning gems

There are also Wishes that can be bound into items by a demon (if a wizard summons one and wins a very dangerous contest of wills with it), and the Blast Trap spell (making the item into a contact bomb).
There are of course quite a few examples of single-use magic items in literature.

I upvoted / accepted this, since the SJ connection means it's almost certainly part of the story. But the thing I remember from whatever book I read, and that struck me from the GURPs description, is that you could effectively cast these spells on pocket litter. Cast "shield" on your leather jacket, cast "fireball" on the tennis ball you found in the park, etc. No obviously magical gems or scrolls, just a bunch of nick knacks.  In the book, the optional break-to-activate mechanic meant magicians tended to collect cheap ceramic toys, since they were cheap and they broke when slammed

@codeMonkey Yes it's clearly different, but has some similarities. No putting just any spell on an object, but there are some specific spells that can be put on arbitrary objects: The Blast Trap I mentioned, but also Conceal, Light, (like Continual Light in GURPS), and some that work on objects of a type, like Lock, Staff, or Brand.
